# Python: Will resaving model with older version of xgboost affect model performance?

Tags: python, xgboost

I have a model that is saved on my local machine using Python 3.9.6 and xgboost==1.6.1. I saved it using:

```
filename = 'model.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

However, I have to load it into an environment that uses Python 3.6.9 and xgboost==1.5.2. I can't upgrade Python in that environment so that I can use xgboost==1.6.1. Is there anything I can do so that I can open my model in this separate environment? If I uninstall and reinstall the older version of xgboost on my local machine to save it in will this affect my model?

Update:
I tried the solution given by James but then I get the error:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 218, in _check_call
    raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
xgboost.core.XGBoostError: [14:36:00] ../include/xgboost/json.h:73: Invalid cast, from Integer to Boolean
Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0xcb05d) [0x7fe0cb50b05d]
  [bt] (1) /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0xd40a5) [0x7fe0cb5140a5]
  [bt] (2) /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x24a7f0) [0x7fe0cb68a7f0]
  [bt] (3) /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x1996f2) [0x7fe0cb5d96f2]
  [bt] (4) /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x17a712) [0x7fe0cb5ba712]
  [bt] (5) /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x1b6432) [0x7fe0cb5f6432]
  [bt] (6) /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(XGBoosterLoadModel+0x5c8) [0x7fe0cb4dec08]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the xgboost docs, use

```
model.save_model("model.json")
model.load_model("model.json")
```

> #### Loading pickled file from different version of XGBoost
>
> As noted, pickled model is neither portable nor stable, but in some cases the pickled models are valuable. One way to restore it in the future is to load it back with that specific version of Python and XGBoost, export the model by calling save_model.

> #### A note on backward compatibility of models and memory snapshots
>
> We guarantee backward compatibility for models but not for memory snapshots.
>
> Models (trees and objective) use a stable representation, so that models produced in earlier versions of XGBoost are accessible in later versions of XGBoost. If you’d like to store or archive your model for long-term storage, use save_model (Python) and xgb.save (R).

> On the other hand, memory snapshot (serialisation) captures many stuff internal to XGBoost, and its format is not stable and is subject to frequent changes. Therefore, memory snapshot is suitable for checkpointing only, where you persist the complete snapshot of the training configurations so that you can recover robustly from possible failures and resume the training process. Loading memory snapshot generated by an earlier version of XGBoost may result in errors or undefined behaviors. If a model is persisted with pickle.dump (Python) or saveRDS (R), then the model may not be accessible in later versions of XGBoost.

- https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/saving_model.html?highlight=save_model#a-note-on-backward-compatibility-of-models-and-memory-snapshots
- https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/saving_model.html?highlight=save_model#loading-pickled-file-from-different-version-of-xgboost
- https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html?highlight=save_model#xgboost.Booster.save_model

Comment: This still doesn't help. I get the error shown above

Comment: Unsure if the issue is with lack of forward compatibility (using a newer model on an older version), or if something else is going on. Have you tried installing using a project specific virtualenv with a requirements.txt file: `python3.9.6 -m venv venv; source venv/bin/activate; echo xgboost==1.6.1 >> requirements.txt; pip install -r requirements.txt`